# Implement double stack to calculate an mathematical expression on command line in C. (Segmentation Fault)

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, stack

I am trying to write a C program that takes an expression like 
**"calc 6 + [ 3 x 4 ]"** and outputs the correct answer (18) using a double stack implementation.

However, I'm having segfault issues and I'm sure it's due to my lack of understanding of char * arrays.

Basically, there are two stacks: valueStack and operandStack. The operand stack checks for three strings (at the moment) "[, +, x" (x for multiplication) and stores them on the operandStack. It uses the pushOpStack function to store the string and then increments the top of the stack.

Annnnd that's pretty much where my trouble is I believe. I'm not sure if I'm actually storing it in the correct place, or if I'm not inputting the correct parameters into the function (or if it's something else entirely). I commented out all of the other sections of the code because they seem irrelevant to this problem; once it's fixed I should be able to figure everything else out.

To continue the logic, when it finds a "]," it will continue to pop the operandStack until it finds a "[" again, and pops the valueStack twice to get the two values to compute repeatedly. This is another issue entirely and I'm not entirely sure if it works yet.

I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you.

```
// calc.c

#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


void pushValStack(int stack[], int *top, int value) {
  stack[(*top)++] = value;
}
int popValStack(int stack[], int *top) {
  return stack[--(*top)];
}

void pushOpStack(char *stack, int *top, char *value) { // PROBLEM WITH THIS FUNCTION ?
  stack[(*top)++] = *value;
}
char *popOnStack(char *stack, int *top) {
  return stack[--(*top)];

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int i, token, j;
  for (i=1; i<argc; i++) { // This code here takes in arguments from the command line
    printf("%s ", argv[i]);
  }
  int valueStack[50];
  char* operand; 
  char operandStack[50]; // Should be char *? Very confused...
  int valueTop;
  int operandTop;
  for(token = 1; token < argc; token++) { // token starts at 1 because "calc" is argv[0]

    printf("]", argv[4]);
    if (strcmp(argv[token], "x") == 0 || strcmp(argv[token], "+") == 0 || strcmp(argv[token], "[") == 0) {
      // printf("%s", argv[token]);
      pushOpStack(operandStack, &operandTop, argv[token]); // WHERE I BELIEVE THE CODE BREAKS!
      printf("%d", operandTop);
    }
    if (strcmp(argv[token], "]") == 0) {
      while(strcmp(operandStack[operandTop], "[") == 1) {
        // operand = popOnStack(operandStack, &operandTop);
        //int m = popValStack(valueStack, &valueTop);
        //printf("%d", m);
        // int n = popValStack(valueStack, &valueTop);
        //printf("%d", n);
        if (strcmp(operand, "+") == 0) {
         // pushValStack(valueStack, &valueTop, n + m);
        }
        else if (strcmp(operand, "x") == 0) {
       //   pushValStack(valueStack, &valueTop, n * m);
        }
      } 
    } 
    else {
      // pushValStack(valueStack, &valueTop, atoi(argv[token]));
    }   
  }
  //printf("%d", valueTop);
  //printf("%d", valueStack[valueTop]);
}
/*
  while(operandTop > 0) {
    operand = popOnStack(operandStack, &operandTop);
    int m = popValStack(valueStack, &valueTop);
    int n = popValStack(valueStack, &valueTop);
    if (*operand == '+') {
      pushValStack(valueStack, &valueTop, n + m);
    }
    else if (*operand == '*') {
      pushValStack(valueStack, &valueTop, n * m);
    }
  }
  return valueStack[valueTop];
*/
```

Comment: I suggest you refactor your code to encapsulate a stack as a `struct` instead of using locals and parameters.

Comment: Debugger......................

Answer (score 1):

The values of `operandTop` and `valueTop` are uninitialized.

If you then use them to index into your stacks then that's most certainly going to segfault.

You're passing them here:

```
pushOpStack(operandStack, &operandTop, argv[token]);
```

and inside `pushOpStack(...)`:

```
stack[(*top)++]
```

i.e. *boom*, segfault.

Comment: I'm surprised this was not detected when running the evaluator under a debugger.  I mean, it's not san.. productive to try to develop an expression evaluator without using a debugger.

Comment: Meh. When dealing with pointers/arrays in C/C++, you have to realize that no-one is going to do any bounds checking for you. One day you will make very useful use of this feature but not until having grinded through a number of segfaults :-)